# Pytest stop_test_suite_after_n_test_failures - Error is displayed

Tags: python, pytest

I am planning stop my execution in PyTest after it encounters n failures.

So I have used the below command:

*pytest filename.py -v --maxfail = 1*

But it displays below error, unable to find the solution. Please throw some light.

ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument --maxfail: invalid int value: '=1'

Comment: Looks like you have spaces around the `=` in your command line. This is not valid.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen. Now working after removing the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

pytest filename.py -v --maxfail=1

Removed the spaces near = (equal to symbol) and it worked like a charm.